# Why hashCode() returns the same value for a object in all consecutive executions?

Tags: java, equality

I am trying some code around object equality in java. As I have read somewhere

> `hashCode()` is a number which is generated by applying the hash function. Hash Function can be different for each object but can also be same. At the object level, it returns the memory address of the object.

Now, I have sample program, which I run 10 times, consecutively. Every time i run the program I get the same value as hash code.

If `hashCode()` function returns the memory location for the object, how come the java(JVM) store the object at same memory address in the consecutive runs?

Can you please give me some insight and your view over this issue?

The Program I am running to test this behavior is below :

```
public class EqualityIndex {

    private int index;

    public EqualityIndex(int initialIndex) {
       this.index = initialIndex;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EqualityIndex ei = new EqualityIndex(2);
        System.out.println(ei.hashCode());
    }

}
```

Every time I run this program the hash code value returned is `4072869`.

Comment: what are your objects? Show some code.

Comment: are you sure your value is a memory address? Can you post it?

Comment: Java's default `.hashCode()` is actually more like an incremental memory *identifier* than *address* so naturally when the preconditions are the same, so is the result.

Comment: 'At the object level, it returns the memory address of the object.' That statement is about 12 years out of date.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> how come the java(JVM) store the object at same memory address in the consecutive runs?

Why wouldn't it? Non-kernel programs never work with absolute memory addresses, they use virtual memory where each process gets its own address space. So it's no surprise at all that a deterministic program would place stuff at the same location in each run.

Comment: It is worth noting that this answer does not apply to modern JVMs. For example, by default JDK7's `Object.hashCode()` does not use the object's address **at all**. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860194/what-is-an-internal-address-in-java/13860488#13860488

Answer (score 4):

Well, the objects may very well end up in the same location in the virtual memory. Nothing contradictory with that. Bottom line is that you shouldn't care anyway. **If** the hashCode is implemented to return something related to the internal storage address (there is no guarantee at all!) there is nothing useful you could do with that information anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The `hashCode()` function should return the same value for the same object in the same execution. It is not necessary to return same value for different execution. See the following comments which was extracted from `Object` class.

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during 
>   an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method 
>   must consistently return the same integer, provided no information 
>   used in equals comparisons on the object is modified.
>   **This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an
>   application to another execution of the same application.**

I have executed your code few times.
Here is my result

`1935465023`

1425840452

`1935465023`

`1935465023`

`1935465023`

1925529038

`1935465023`

`1935465023`

The same number is repeated multiple times. But that doesn't mean they are same always. Lets assume, a particular implementation of JVM is looking for first free slot in the memory. then if you don't run any other applications, the chances for allocating the object in the same slot is high.

Answer (score 2):

Which kinds of object you are created? Is it a specific kind of object like String (e.g). If it is a specific kind, the class can already override the hashCode() method and return it to you. In that case, what you receive is not memory address any more.

and also what values you receive, are you sure if it is memory address?

So, please post more code for more details

Answer (score 2):

> As I have read somewhere: *" ... At the object level, it returns the memory address of the object."*

That statement is incorrect, or at best an oversimplification.

The statement is referring to the default implementation of `Object.hashCode()` which returns the same value as `System.identityHashcode(Object)`.

The Javadoc for `Object.hashCode()` says this:

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)

and this:

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified.

In fact, the identity hashcode value is typically based on the Object's machine address *when the method is first called for the object*.  The value is stored in a hidden field in the Object header.  This allows the same hashcode to be returned on subsequent calls ... even if the GC has relocated the Object in the meantime.

Note that if the identity hashcode value did change over the lifetime of an Object, it would violate the contract for `hashcode()`, and would be useless as a hashcode.

Answer (score 1):

hashCode can and may be overridden by the class you are using, [the JavaDoc for Object.hashCode()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) states that it is '... typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer...' so the actual implementation may be system dependant.  Note also the third point in the JavaDoc that two objects that are not equal are not required to return different hashCodes.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("i: " + i + ", hashCode: " + new Object().hashCode());
}
```

prints:

```
i: 0, hashCode: 1476323068
i: 1, hashCode: 535746438
i: 2, hashCode: 2038935242
i: 3, hashCode: 988057115
i: 4, hashCode: 1932373201
i: 5, hashCode: 1001195626
i: 6, hashCode: 1560511937
i: 7, hashCode: 306344348
i: 8, hashCode: 1211154977
i: 9, hashCode: 2031692173
```

Comment: Interesting.  What JVM are you using?

Comment: java -version:
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

If two objects are equal, they have to have the same hash codes. So, as long as you do not create plain `Object` instances, everytime you create object that has the same value, you'll get the same hash code.

Comment: it is not always true. It depends on the class you are talking about. It is a good convention to always override equals and hashCode but it is not always true

Comment: When you say "have to have", you really mean "ought to have".  There is nothing in the language or runtime system that *prevents* you from breaking contract for `hashcode()` and `equals()`.  But if you do, anything that uses hashing on your object will behave incorrectly.

Comment: The point is that *all* objects *ought to* obey the hashcode / equals contract, not just those that are "comparable" ... whatever that means.

Comment: Yeah, I meant *ought to have*.