# Is there a reason Object.hashCode() is 31-bit?

Tags: java, hashcode

If you run the following on HotSpot Java 7 64-bit version.

```
int countTopBit = 0, countLowestBit = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    int h = new Object().hashCode();
    if (h < 0)
        countTopBit++;
    if ((h & 1) == 1)
        countLowestBit++;
}
System.out.println("The count of negative hashCodes was " + countTopBit + ", the count of odd hashCodes was " + countLowestBit);
```

you can get a result like

```
The count of negative hashCodes was 0, the count of odd hashCodes was 49994232
```

I was wondering if this means the `Object.hashCode()` is only really 31-bit and why this might be so?

---

It is not the case that the top bit is not used. From the source for HashMap

```
257   /**
258    * Applies a supplemental hash function to a given hashCode, which
259    * defends against poor quality hash functions.  This is critical
260    * because HashMap uses power-of-two length hash tables, that
261    * otherwise encounter collisions for hashCodes that do not differ
262    * in lower bits. Note: Null keys always map to hash 0, thus index 0.
263    */
264   static int hash(int h) {
265       // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
266       // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
267       // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
268       h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
269       return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
270   }
```

Comment: This might be as an optimization.  Hash tables often take the hash code mod the number of buckets, but have to mask off the top bit first to avoid a negative index.  Perhaps this is to avoid that step later?

Comment: @templatetypedef I did wonder this might be the case, but I suspect Object.hashCode() is not used in Hash collections that often as it is usually overriden with a 32-bit hashCode(). Also HashMap mutates the raw hashCode so the top bit is used.

Comment: @templatetypedef: but what about user overrides that don't do this? Hash table still needs to deal with this

Comment: Same code for C# gives: "The count of negative hashCodes was 0, the count of odd hashCodes was 50000002", so the question might be valid for .net as well :)

Comment: I agree that this doesn't always work because of overriding.  However, it might be possidle for the VM internals to take advantage of it.

Comment: Did you try this on 64-bit or 32-bit process? From [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()): "This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but..." - if all of your objects are allocated in the lowest 2GB of address space, than this implementation would never return a value with the high bit set. (And especially since each of these objects becomes instant garbage, you're likely always allocating in the same region of memory)

Comment: @templatetypedef I have updates my question to show that the top bit is used.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The actual address is not used directly. e.g. all objects are on an 8-byte boundary so the lowest 3 bits are also 0 in the address, but not the in the hashCode. See an earlier question which show that objects with the same address don't get the same hashCode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860194/what-is-an-internal-address-in-java

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HotSpot supports a variety of hashing algorithms for `Object`. As you've discovered emprically, the top bit is always masked out before the result is returned:

```
// src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp
static inline intptr_t get_next_hash(Thread * Self, oop obj) {
   ...
   value &= markOopDesc::hash_mask;
   ...
   return value;
}
```

`markOopDesc::hash_mask` is computed as follows:

```
  enum { age_bits                 = 4,
         lock_bits                = 2,
         biased_lock_bits         = 1,
         max_hash_bits            = BitsPerWord - age_bits - lock_bits - biased_lock_bits,
         hash_bits                = max_hash_bits > 31 ? 31 : max_hash_bits,
         ...
         hash_mask               = right_n_bits(hash_bits),
```

As you can see, `markOopDesc::hash_mask` always has bit 31 set to zero.

As to why this is done, your guess is as good as mine. It could have been that the original developer felt that only dealing with positive integers would simplify things down the line. For all we know, it could even be an off-by-one error in the `hash_bits` computation. ;-)

Comment: +1 As SWeko found, C# does the same thing which suggests there might have been a common reason. Or it could be they copied a common implementation which did this for reasons which no longer apply.

Comment: It could be possible that `right_n_bits` does not take 32 as an argument correctly.  I am building Java 8 to so I have a copy of the source to refer to. ;)