# Default behaviour of hashCode()

Tags: java

I continuously run this program on the same machine:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println(test.hashCode());
    }
}
```

The result is the same each time I run the program on my machine (Windows 7 64 bit):
4384790

On another machine (Windows server 2008, 64 bit), most times it gives me :1671711. However some times the result is : 11394033.

On my machines I run the program under Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_26/1.6.0_33

I have read the documentation for Object class:

> *As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This
>   is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the
>   object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not
>   required by the JavaTM programming language.)*

But if *hashCode()* is indeed implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, I still do not understand why the Java VM assigns the same address for the Test object each time I run it.

Is is known exactly how the default *hashCode()* operates?

Comment: It is very carefully *not* specified, and as you have discovered it varies by platform.

Comment: I *think* the "internal address" is not the physical address in RAM, but something internal to the JVM, which probably starts at the same "logical" value each time - therefor if you always create the same object in the same class it would always wind up as the "first" one based on the "logical" address-scheme (again: I'm just speculating)

Comment: @Perception: The accepted answer to that other question does not apply to modern JVMs. Please see my answer below for an explanation (in a nutshell, the object's address is not used *at all* by `Object.hashCode()`).

Answer (score 5):

The details are JVM-specific. Furthermore, some (most?) JVMs support multiple `hashCode()` algorithms (when starting the JVM, you can choose which one it would use).

Interestingly, most of those algorithms -- including Oracle's defaults -- do not use the object's address **at all**. For example, JDK7's default `hashCode()` uses a global pseudo-random number generator, and then caches the generated pseudo-random hash code within the object's header.

Of course, a psuedo-random generator would always give the same sequence of numbers if initialized the same way.

For the details of an investigation I've done in the past, see [What is an "internal address" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860194/what-is-an-internal-address-in-java/13860488#13860488)

Answer (score 3):

Non-kernel programs never work with absolute memory addresses, they use virtual memory where each process gets its own address space. So a program would place data at the same location in each run.

Comment: True as it may be, this has no bearing on `Object.hashCode()` (at least in modern Oracle JVMs). See my answer for details.